# How to include autogenerated hbm.xml files into WAR with Gradle

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate

I'm using gradle in Eclipse. I've generated some entity classes and their associated hbm.xml using hibernate code generation.

`My folder structure is 
src/main/java/entity
-class.java
-class.hbm.xml`

I'm using gradle to build the WAR file with

```
war{
    from {
    (configurations.runtime).collect {
   it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
   }
}    
baseName = 'RestAPI'
archiveName = 'RestAPI.war'}
```

But when I run the war build and check the archive, the entity folder is there inside WEB-INF along with the classes that hibernate generated for me and the rest of my application. However, none of the hbm.xml files are anywhere to be found in the war file.
I've read some other stackoverflow answers that seemed to imply I could put these xml files in the resources folder. I've tried that, and it indeed copies those xml files into the war package when they're there, but I'd rather keep them in the entity package.

Is there a configuration somewhere that's excluding these XML files, or do I need to somehow explicitly tell the war plugin to include these XML files?